# como faço para o document w não substituir o código de um site?

Tags: javascript

sempre que eu uso document.write, tudo o codigo do site é substituído, tem como fazer isso sem o codigo ser substituído?

o site não me deixa publica a pergunta sem uma imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia explicar melhor o que está fazendo?Como posso reproduzir o erro?

Comment: eu criei um evento de click para quando eu clicasse em um obj criararia um <p>, mas quando se usar o document.write para cria-lo, o código no site é subistituido apenas pelo <p>

Answer (score 0):

Defina o id na tag que você deseja inserir esse parágrafo, com por exemplo "content". E defina o conteúdo da seguinte maneira:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<p>New text!</p>";
```